# Update Dimensional Concurrent Dictionary

Tags: vb.net

I have this little function that I found but I am having a hard time trying to call it correctly. how can I call it to update my ConcurrentDictionary

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Animals As New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, String())
        Dim iKey = "key123456"

        Animals(iKey) = {"cat", "dog", "bird"}

        Dim success As Boolean = TryUpdate(Animals, iKey, Func("cat", "frog"))
    End Sub

    Function TryUpdate(Of TKey, TValue)(dict As Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of TKey, TValue), key As TKey, updateFactory As Func(Of TValue, TValue)) As Boolean
        Dim curValue As TValue
        If Not dict.TryGetValue(key, curValue) Then
            Return False
        End If
        dict.TryUpdate(key, updateFactory(curValue), curValue)
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You may want to use `AddOrUpdate` instead of TryUpdate. Running TryGetValue and then doing TryUpdate may run into concurrency issues, i.e. the value may not exist when you do a check, but may disappear when you do TryUpdate (from another thread).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TryUpdate has three parameters,

1. the ConcurrentDictionary to be updated,
2. the Key to be updated in the dictionary, and
3. a delegate function that accepts the key's current value, and returns the desired value.

   ```
   Dim success As Boolean = TryUpdate(myDictionary, myKey, Func(oldval) newval)
   ```

How you pass the third parameter is up to you, but it looks like the intention is so you can have a look at the old value to ensure it is what you expected, then passing either your new value, or the returned value accordingly.

---

Addition for clarity: The third parameter is expecting to be passed a delegate to a function which will accept the current value of the key you are trying to change, and return a new value (or the original value, if you don't want to change it).

Here I'm creating a function `CheckValue` that determines if the old value is what I expected, then if so returns the new value. The `myDel` is a delegate of that function which is passed into `TryUpdate`.

```
Dim whatIExpected As String = ""
Dim newVal As String = ""
Dim myDel As Func(Of String, String) = AddressOf CheckValue
Public Function CheckValue(ByVal oldVal As String) As String
    If (oldVal = whatIExpected) Then
        Return newVal
    Else
        Return oldVal
    End If
End Function

'Then later inside some function or sub..
whatIExpected = "cat"
newVal = "frog"
Dim success As Boolean = TryUpdate(myDictionary, myKey, myDel)
```

Comment: See [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) for an explanation.

Comment: What's the error? I'm writing this from memory, so surely I could have forgotten some details.

Comment: Error 1 Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.

Comment: I updated my answer to be more concise and deleted my unclear comment. I hope that helps.